# How to get values from a 2D $_GET?

Tags: php

I need to get the Type value (1 & 8) from the $_GET. Please see the content of $_GET when using print_r($_GET);

```
Array
(
    [pageid] => 0
    [project] => 1
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [GroupName] => RGB
                    [Type] => 1
                    [IDs] => 38;39;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;106
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [GroupName] => GeoJSON
                    [Type] => 8
                    [IDs] => 44;49
                )

        )
```

Currently I am trying

```
$type = $_GET["groups"]["Type"];
_log("type: " .$type);
```

This does not return any values. Later on, these Type's values will be used for SQL queries.
Ex.:

```
if ($type != "%" && $type != "8") {

} elseif ($type == "8"){

}
```

Comment: Since groups is an array, you'll have to either pass the index you want to find (`$_GET['groups'][0]['Type']`) or retrieve the Type column using array_column, like this `array_column($_GET['groups'], 'Type')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many groups within your GET, so assume they're added dynamically. The best way for getting each one is... iterating the sub-array

```php
foreach ($_GET['groups'] as $group){
    var_dump($group['Type']);
}
```

if you want just to get the type of the first group without iteration, just use

```
var_dump($_GET['groups'][0]['Type']);
```

for second

```
var_dump($_GET['groups'][1]['Type']);
```

etc.